# Swift conditional data printing on UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, row, segue

I have an UITableView, this is its cellForRowAtIndexPath and its numberOfRowsInSection:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customTableViewCell") as! UITableViewCell
    let task = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Task

        cell.textLabel?.text = task.summary
        var detail = task.detail
        var context = task.context
        var due = task.date
        var status = task.status
        var responsible = task.responsable
        var folder = task.folder

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Contexte: \(context), Detail: \(detail), Status: \(status), Ending date: \(due)"

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let numberOfRowsInSection = frc.sections?[section].numberOfObjects
    return numberOfRowsInSection!

}
```

What I'm trying to do is , when I click on a line, it opens a detail view of the line, so I try to pass datas with a prepareForSegue but I only succeed to send on the segue datas from my database and not datas from the selected line, like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {



    if let identifier = segue.identifier{

        //On vérifie que l'identifier est le bon, permet d'envoyer qu'à la View qu'on veut si a le risque d'envoyer à plusieurs. Si on veut envoyer ailleurs, il suffit de créer la vue en question et de rajouter un "case" avec le nom du nouvel identifier.
        switch identifier {
            case "Show Detail":
                //Creation du lien vers la base SQLite


                let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Task", inManagedObjectContext: self.context!)
                let request = NSFetchRequest()
                request.entity = entityDescription
                var cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customTableViewCell") as! UITableViewCell

                var error: NSError?
                var objects = self.context?.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)
                let match = objects![0] as! NSManagedObject

                let editTaskVC = segue.destinationViewController as! EditTaskViewController
                if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell){

                        editTaskVC.Name = match.valueForKey("summary") as! String
                        editTaskVC.Detail = match.valueForKey("detail") as! String
                        editTaskVC.Status = match.valueForKey("status") as! String
                        editTaskVC.Owner = match.valueForKey("responsable") as! String
                        editTaskVC.Context = match.valueForKey("context") as! String
                        editTaskVC.IdValue = match.valueForKey("id") as? String
                        editTaskVC.Field = match.valueForKey("folder") as! String
                        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
                        let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(match.valueForKey("date") as! String)
                        editTaskVC.EndDatePicker?.date = date!

                }
            default: break
        }
    }

}
```

What I try to do, is sending to the destinationViewController datas from the just clicked row and not the database, something like this:

```
editTaskVC.Name = cell.textLabel?.text
```

I have searched on the net and saw some solutions, like using the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems with your approach.

For starters you should not be calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` outside of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Next, you basic approach is wrong.

View objects do not store state, they display it and collect input from the user. A table view cell can be scrolled off the screen at any time and it's current settings will be lost. When the user makes changes to the values of a cell you need to save that to a model object that stores the current state of you data.

Normally this means saving changes to your database if that's what you're using as a model. If you want the changes to stay pending until the user clicks a save button, or for some other reason are not ready to save the changes to your database then you need to save them to some data model specific to the table view. An array managed by the view controller works well for this.

In any case, when the user taps a cell, you should be looking in the data for your table view for the data to pass on to the detail controller, not trying to read it from the cell.

What you want to do is to save the indexPath of the tapped cell to an instance variable. Then in prepareForSegue, if you figure out that this is a segue triggered by the user tapping a cell, look at that indexPath and fetch the appropriate data for that indexPath to pass on to the next view controller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'll take a look about what was wrong with me and then correct my code, I think it should be ok with your explanations. I do some tests and accept your answer if it's ok.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you destination view controller is not affected because you do:

```
if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell){
    //code
}
```

This condition is always false.
Remove this condition and normally it should work.

NB: see Duncan C post.